# About Integrate Clojure into springboot framework

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, clojure

I'm currently trying to integrate clojure into gradle springboot project, even though it works, I do have to use `RT.loadClassForName("au.edu.uq.core");` before the `Clojure.var` could access the function, if I comment the `RT.loadClassForName("au.edu.uq.core");`, there will be an error like:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'au.edu.uq.core/hello-from-clojure.

But in the build.gradle I already include `classes.dependsOn compileClojure`.

There are screenshots of build.gradle, Main Java Class and the clojure namespace. This is a tiny demo project for me to learn gradle, any suggestions to make this build process more elegant?

Starting script is `./gradlew bootRun` and `./gradlew run`

//This is the Java Main Class
[image]

//This is the clojure namespace
[image]

//This is the build.gradle
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This might be an interesting question, but please give a little more attention to the formatting, and get the code out of those screenshots (I mean, seriously?).

Comment: Please don't use screen shots to show code.  Screenshots can not be searched (yet?) and for someone to answer your question, copying code over into the answer is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I got from the screenshot of the Main class, it seems you are using `Clojure.lang.RT` to load your function, while the [official reference documentation](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#_calling_clojure_from_java) suggests otherwise:

> Functions in `clojure.core` are automatically loaded. Other namespaces
>   can be loaded via `require`:
>
> ```
> IFn require = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "require");
> require.invoke(Clojure.read("clojure.set"));
> ```

My suggestion would be to try something like:

```
IFn require = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "require");
require.invoke(Clojure.read("au.edu.uq.core"));
IFn helloFunction = Clojure.var("au.edu.uq.core", "hello-from-clojure");
helloFunction.invoke();
```